# New video card HIS 7790 OC 1GB: sytem doesn't boot

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, amd-radeon

I've upgraded my old video card Gygabyte 7750 to HIS 7790 IceQ Turbo. After installation of card onto mobo, plugging power into video card and powering on, system starts but doesn't boot. Power is on, fans rotate, but there's no video signal. I don't even see BIOS POST screen.

PSU: Chieftec 450-80p
MB: MSI H61M-P20 (G3)
CPU: Intel g850
RAM: Goodram 2x4GB (1333)
HDD: 64GB Crucial m4 SSD + 80GB HITACHI sata2
MON: AOC i2369Vm (connected via hdmi)

System consumes very little power, so it's definitely not a PSU insufficiency problem.

EDIT: SOLVED by updating mobo BIOS

Comment: Do you even see the motherboard post screen? I was under the impression that the 7790 uses a custom driver version specific to that model -- maybe the old driver is causing an issue?

Comment: @Ash, thanks for reply. No, I mentioned in my post that i don't see POST screen.

Comment: Your graphics card was a pretty significant upgrade.  How much power does each of those graphic cards require?  Have you verified all the plugs are pluged in, the card is secure, because this problem is a clasic signed of one of two things.  The first your system has a very small power supply for the type of card you have the second is would be explained by a short.

Comment: @Ramhound, I had no issues with previous video card 7750. overclockers.com says that HIS 7790 Turbo consumes ~200 watts. So my PSU is enough powerful.

Comment: @Alex, sorry, was just double-checking since it didn't explicitly say "no post" at the time. Do you have another computer that you can try the card in? It may be DOA. What is your PSU make/model out of interest?

Comment: @Ash - The brand of PSU is already listed in the question.

Comment: @AlexAntonov - Overclockers isn't HIS check the manual for exact requirements.  Additional how many PCI-E power plugs does each card require?

Comment: @Ramhound, [here's](http://www.overclockers.com/hd-7790-icooler-turbo-graphics-card-review/) overclockers test of HIS 7790. The only difference is in cooling system. GPU requires one 6pin connector.

Comment: @AlexAntonov - The test system has a 1000W power supply.  Even overclockers report on the card itself, says the requirement is at least a 500W power supply, I don't care what "other people" said I care about what the article and what the manufacture says.  Simply stated **You need a better power supply**

Comment: I won't argue that the power supply is a potential issue, but the TDP of the 7790 is only 85W...there should be enough power, unless the PSU is faulty or so old it can't deliver it's labelled 20A/20A on the 12V rails. (Getting a brand new good quality PSU would be a great option even if it isn't the problem).

Comment: @Ash, thank you, I already found a solution and I'll post it soon.

Comment: @Alex: good to hear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all guys, but as i suspected, the problem was definitely not in my PSU.
Fortunately, I came across a similar post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/607027/system-wont-boot-gigabyte-hd-7790-1gb-oc-gpu-issue-or-corsair-vs550-psu-issue?rq=1) and I assumed my problem may be the same.
So, i updated my mobo BIOS and... The problem is FIXED!

Comment: Glad my post helped someone! I just dread trying to sell my 7790 one day on ebay if lots of people will need a mobo upgrade just to use it... definitely something to consider when buying one.

Answer (score 0):

Some graphics cards are very particular about installation, including what you do before you even install it. One of the biggest issues people run into is not matching system requirements.

According to the manufacturer's system requirements ([product manual](http://www.hisdigital.com/UserFiles/product/53188_enu_1.0_eng%5B1%5D.pdf)), this card requires ***minimum*** a 500 watt PSU. You only have a 450.

It also requires 64 bit OS, which you did not indicate what you are using.

Lastly, it states you must uninstall the old graphic drivers BEFORE you install this card and it's drivers.

These things are likely the reason you are not getting a signal to your monitor. You may need to reinstall your old card to get things working again, then start the installation over once your system meets the minimum requirements.

Comment: as i mentioned earlier, OS (and surely driver) is not a problem since I have no video signal at all. Manufacturers usually overstate sys requirements because a lot of chip chinese PSUs are on the market. My power supply is a brand PSU which is certified with 80 plus standart. A lot of people on the forums confirm that 450 watts good PSU is more than enough to run even overclocked amd 7790 card.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I don't understand why you're asking for help then. Your system doesn't meet the minimum systems requirements and (as far as I can tell) you haven't followed the installation instructions, yet you want us to tell you why it's not working. Just because you think it should work, doesn't mean it will. There is always the possibility its a defective card. Have you called the manufacturer?

Comment: @AlexAntonov - But its not working and the symptoms you describe indicate IT IS a power problem.  Furthermore a bronze certified power supply is one of the lowest ratings you can get.

Comment: Thank you guys for support, i found solution! (And yeah, my PSU is not the reason of trouble). I'll post solution soon (because of my reputation).