# Why does my computer refuse to boot with a Radeon graphics card?

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, amd-radeon, firmware

This is a really strange question, I know, but I have a computer here that refuses to boot with any ATi/AMD Radeon card installed.

When any Radeon card is installed in the machine, all fans will spin without issue (and do not stop, even after a period of five minutes), but the board never gives the initial chirp that it is powered up and nothing is ever output to the display.  The machine does not respond to any keyboard input (including toggling num lock) over USB or PS/2, though the desired build uses USB.  Probing the motherboard's power pins show 12V around 12.131V median, 5V around 5.013V median, and 3.3V at exactly 3.30V.  PWR_OK is solid and the total power output hovers around 92W.  When connecting a GeForce, however, the computer immediately boots up, chirps, and displays the Intel logo.

I feel like I'm going mad.  Certainly Intel didn't create a firmware that refuses to work with an AMD graphics card... did they?  Why would this machine refuse to boot with a Radeon card?

**Cards that work**:

- EVGA GeForce 9800GTX+ OC edition (x16)
- XFX GeForce GTS 250 (x16)
- PNY GeForce GT 730 (x8)

**Cards that don't work**:

- XFX Radeon HD 5770 (x16)
- MSI Radeon HD 6450M (x8)
- XFX Radeon R5 220 Low Power (x16)
- Gigabyte Radeon R7 240 (x16)

**Computer specifications**:

- Intel DP43TF motherboard running firmware version NBG4310H.86A
- EVGA 550W power supply (additionally tested all cards on a 600W PSU)
- Seagate Barracuda 7200.9 LP 1TB disk on SATA port 0
- Sony DRU-810A DVD+RW drive on IDE channel 1
- 6 GB DDR2-667MHz memory in two pairs - 2x1GB, 2x2GB
- No other PCI or PCI Express cards installed
- USB keyboard, mouse, and printer
- If it matters, Dell S2415H 24" monitor over HDMI

Considering the fact that my trusty old overclocked 9800GTX+ works, yet a very low power R5 does not work, it really does not feel power related.  However, I am open to any suggestion, and I may be able to pull a 730W PSU out of a friend's workstation for testing if it would be worth the test.

Comment: This is something you should ask the mainboard's hardware support team, in my opinion.

Comment: "Certainly Intel didn't create a firmware that refuses to work with an AMD graphics card." No your just missing something obvious

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/661711/new-video-card-his-7790-oc-1gb-sytem-doesnt-boot?rq=1

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/1010794/new-graphics-card-preventing-boot-up?rq=1

Comment: @Ramhound, the first link isn't quite helpful because it is already running the latest available firmware revision available.  The second link however makes me sad.  That is a very similar model to mine.

Answer (score 0):

Intel's support division contacted me over Twitter confirming that there is a bug in the firmware of this board and similar ones (such as in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1010794/new-graphics-card-preventing-boot-up?rq=1)).